# Process returned error code 2

Tags: compiler-errors, contiki

What does this error mean in contiki? the code is based on udp-sink.sky in `examples/ipv6/rpl-collect` and the error occurs when I try to add the powertrace to it.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.5.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: udp-sink.sky section `.data' will not fit in region `rom'
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.5.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: section .vectors loaded at [0000ffe0,0000ffff] overlaps section .data loaded at [0000ffae,00010097]
/usr/lib/gcc/msp430/4.5.3/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: region `rom' overflowed by 184 bytes
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Process returned error code 2
make: *** [udp-sink.sky] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have an object file that exceeds the size limitations of the device that you are compiling for. Specifically, you have overflowed the ROM partition, which is usually the region where executed code exists, by 184 bytes. If you reduce the ROM partition by removing 184 bytes of CODE, you should not see that error anymore.